# Elasticsearch Script sort taking too long

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using Script to sort the results(or matches) returned by Elasticsearch.

The Query Look like this.

```
GET trademark7/_search
{
  "size" :20,
  "track_scores": true,
    "stored_fields": [
      "_source"
      ],
    "sort": {
      "_script":{
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
          "id": "algo_for_sorting",
          "params":{
            "query":"linkedin"
          }
        },
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    },
    "query" : {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "tm_applied_for_phonetic": {
                "query": "linkedin"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "tm_applied_for_anan" : {
                 "query" : "linkedin"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

The Problem is that:-

As soon as i use the field **tm_applied_for_anan** for matching Documents. It returns me a lot of results(or matches) because it is tokenized using Anangram and It takes a Lot of time (5 min) for results to appear.

The reasons probably are :-

1) The painless script run slow.

2) The Algorithm i'm using is slow. (I can not change it, this algorithm given by some government or something, I don't know.)

3) Elasticsearch has to apply this slow algorithm to all the results( say 400,000 of them) to calculate score and sort them.

To solve the above mentioned problem, what i want to do is that

1) Let Elasticsearch give me the results with scores calculated by using **Term Frequency** and **Inverse Term Frequency** and all that good stuff, Which is really-really fast.

2) I will apply the slower Algorithm on small number of results (say on TOP 10,000), and Again sort the Results.

My Question is that **"Is there a way i can apply Re-Scoring and Re-Sorting for only a small chunk of the results returned by Elasticsearch inside Elasticsearch?" If not, please Suggest me some Ideas or Your Thoughts!**

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you don't use `_score` in the sorting script you could use filter whose result is cached in elasticsearch**

So try the below query and let me know :

```
GET trademark7/_search
{
    "size": 20,
    "track_scores": true,
    "stored_fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "id": "algo_for_sorting",
                "params": {
                    "query": "linkedin"
                }
            },
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "linkedin",
                        "fields": [
                            "tm_applied_for_phonetic",
                            "tm_applied_for_anan"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i'm using _score for sorting. It has some weightage.

Comment: Okay, then try optimize the script `algo_for_sorting`. You could use doc values, if you are not using it.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals

Comment: Probably you missed the fact that, query in Filter context does not give any score. So, using sorting when score is all zero or the same, does not makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I know filter doesn't contribute to score that's why I have written If you don't use the _score field then try the query. Otherwise I don't see any optimization other than the script  `algo_for_sorting`

Comment: If you provide sort script then the value return from the script is used to sort not the _score

Comment: yes you are right.I will have to optimize the `algo_for_sorting`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212290/discussion-between-abhinav-keshri-and-ashraful-islam).